# Launch second Intent & View from Main Activity and display ProgressDialog with Thread

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-progressbar

I'm having some problems displaying a ProgressDialog. I have a method that scrapes information from a website, and I want to show the user some kind of "Loading" window instead of the app just looking like it is hanging for a second or two when it is working.

Everything works fine when I don't implement a ProgressDialog & Thread, but as soon as I try to implement a Thread to do the heavy lifting, the AboutMe View window is empty.

I have a MainActivity with a TextView that registers a OnClickListener.

A Click on the TextView does a:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AboutMe.class));
```

This is most of the AboutMe.class Activity:

```
public class AboutMe extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog aboutMeProgressDialog;
private String htmlAboutMe = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getAboutMe(); // Get information from Internet

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    setContentView(R.layout.abutme);

    TextView tvAbout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutMe);
    tvAbout.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlAboutMe));

}

private void getAboutMe() {
    try {
        aboutMeProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AboutMe.this, "", "Loading");
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                                /** Code to scape webpage **/
                }
                catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        aboutMeProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

I'm clearly missing out on something trivial, but I've tried to Google just about everything I can think of, but still can't get a Thread together with ProgressDialog to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use run on ui thread method 
instead of handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);  use this code and remove handle message

```
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     aboutMeProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

dude let me know if this was successful,it works most of times

Comment: Well, that sort of worked. I put all my html scraping code in the run() but I never get to see the ProgressDialog, so I must be placing it at the wrong section? Also, I wasn't allowed to use the @Override, Eclipse says "The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method"

Answer (score 0):

please call getAboutMe() method after calling  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either. I mean, the Thread and ProgressbarDialog are clearly executed, but when the ProgressbarDialog is closed, the AboutMe View window behind it is just a small empty box in the middle of the screen.

Comment: if u don't please send the full source as prject i will try

Comment: I would send you a Eclipse project to you, if I knew how to do it.